# Open GUI as admin

Tags: sudo

I'm new to linux and I'll try not to make this ranty but is there an easy way to open a GUI app as sudo?

Is it asking for much for the context menu to have "Run as sudo" or at the least "Open in finder" so I can see where it's installed?

I figure I can run sudo, gksu, gksudo or all of the above if I can hunt down the location.

Is there some tool to make this simple task easier? The program below seems to be getting some permission denied problem when run regularly.

[image]

Comment: You get the permission denied for files and locations that are important to the OS 'inner workings' - these folders and files are not to be accessed as normal user. I'd say there has been quite a lot of thought gone into setting up things w.r.t. root access, for your own good and peace of mind - learn to accept those settings; i.e. do not `sudo` (run as root) just out of habit, put some thought into it.

Comment: You can find the location of the binary/script that is run using `whereis`, `which`, `location` (after doing `sudo updatedb &` to update the locate database in the background), and a few other ways. It might help you say what app, and what actions you're trying to use.

Comment: "Running a GUI as `root`" is discouraged. It can screw up permissions, stir your system with a `root` stick,  and has failed before.